# Smooth LiDAR TIFF Data

Tags: qgis, lidar

I have LiDAR data as a TIFF file.  As expected, human-made structures such as buildings show up as high points.  I would like to have just ground-level elevations. I believe that what I want to do is replace the building high point elevations with the elevation of the adjacent points.  Could anyone suggest a way to do this?  I am using QGIS 3.

Answer (score 1):

Your lidar-derived raster is known as a *DSM* (Digital *Surface* Model), which depicts the top surface of objects such as buildings and trees.  Most (all?) lidar data collection projects have the ability to concurrently acquire bare-earth data, known as a *DTM* (Digital *Terrain* Model) wherein above-ground objects (trees, buildings) are removed.  While it might be possible to remove above-ground objects from a DSM, it would be far, far, far(!) easier to acquire the DTM from the data provider, or failing that, create your own DTM from the lidar point cloud.

Comment: Thanks!  I will try to acquire DTM data.  I have used Maryland Statewide LiDAR, and will check with them first: https://lidar.geodata.md.gov:8443/ExpressZip .  I am looking specifically for DTM data for the Antietam battlefield.