# Converting DEM raster (NetCDF file) into point cloud (LAS file) using Python

Tags: raster, dem, convert, lidar, las

I would like to convert a DEM raster NetCDF file (*.nc) to point cloud LAS file (LAS/LAZ) using Python language. I have been doing the research but still don't have a result. I also have a look on GDAL and PDAL, but there is no specific documents mentioning about this.

Answer (score 2):

Check [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/407217/convert-dsm-to-dtm-and-ndsm/407698#407698) out.

This solution works if you have your DEM as TIFF format. But if you can extract the XYZ coordinates from the NetCDF file yourself and save it to a text file, then you can use [LAStools](http://lastools.org/download/txt2las_README.txt) to create LAS file.
although LAStools is a command line tool but you can use it in python:

```
def convert_txt_to_las(txt_path, out_las_path):
    command = 'txt2las -parse xyz -i {input_txt} -o {output_las}'
    os.system(command.format(input_txt=txt_path, output_las=out_las_path))
```

Comment: Hi Parsa! Thank you so so much for your help! I successfully made it :)). Yayyy!